# Stencil setup: resolve, rollup version

Tags: rollupjs, stenciljs, plugin-node-resolve

I have two problems, both related to setting up my project.

The ultimate goal is to build some web components that communicate vis OSC using [node-osc](https://github.com/MylesBorins/node-osc#readme).

1. My first attempt to set up the project and create a component that uses node-osc resulted in the following message:

   ```
   Bundling Warning UNRESOLVED_IMPORT
   'node-osc' is imported by ./src/components/r-channel/r-channel.tsx, but could not be resolved – treating it
   as an external dependency
   ```

   This gave me a successful build, but my components don't render, so I assume it's not actually all that successful.
2. After some reading, my guess is that I should at least try plugin-node-resolve. I've installed and added to my stencil.config.ts, and am now seeing:

   ```
   Rollup: Plugin Error
   Insufficient rollup version: "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve" requires at least rollup@2.78.0 but found
   rollup@2.42.3. (plugin: node-resolve, buildStart)
   ```

   ...although my package-lock.json seems to indicate that I've got rollup@2.79.1 installed.

Comment: IIRC, rollup is bundled within Stencil (via rollup ), so maybe you'll have to upgrade your Stencil version to get a newer Rollup? Anyway, I'm not sure you'll have any luck using `node-osc` from a browser since it seems to rely on native sockets (you might have to run it in a server application and communicate with that from your frontend, but not sure).

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're right - this would eventually interact with an app running on a node server. Maybe what this means is that the challenge is getting the components to interact with the server, rather than installing node-osc...

Answer (score 0):

StencilJs has an installation of rollup inside its package and it is outdated, So the rollup package you installed is being ignored.
Based on Stencil support they have a lot of customisations on top of current rollup version and they have difficulty updating that package. But they are working on it so the only way is to wait for them to update rollup package.
Here is a link to an open issue on their side:
https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/2526